# Scaling of docker compose services results in port conflict

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I defined a service in `docker-compose.yml` in the following way:

```yaml
version : "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080-8082:80
```

When I try to start three instances of this service with the command

```sh
docker-compose up -d --scale web=5 -d
```

one instance is started, but when docker-compose tries to start the other instances, they produce the error message

```
ERROR: for nginxtest_web_1  Cannot start service web: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) 
is normally permitted.
```

Sometimes two instance are started successfully and only one instance fails. The runtime behavior seems to be quite random. Obviously, docker-compose assigns the same host port to multiple nginx instances. When I repeat the above command two more times all instances get started with different host ports assigned. This error also occurs with other docker images. When I omit the host port range in the `docker-compose.yml` file different random host ports are assigned and everything works as expected.

I use docker version 19.03.12 and docker-compose 1.29.0 on Windows 10 (WSL 2).

Is this a docker-compose bug? Is there any workaround?

**Update:**
Of course I only scale to 3 instances (the number of ports in my host port range)

```sh
docker-compose up -d --scale web=3 -d
```

Answer (score 2):

After scaling up, you can try:

```
docker compose restart
```

This is the current workaround that I had figured out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant!  I hate that this bug exists, but `restart` works great on Windows 10 with WSL 2.  It works in Docker Compose v3 and v3.4 (whether or not `deploy.replicas` is also specified).  I added the `--no-start` flag to `up` so containers are created but not started.  I call them in one command with `docker compose up -d --scale web=5 --no-start; docker compose restart` and all the containers start correctly.  Note that `docker compose start` does not work for me.

Comment: Make sure `docker-compose.yml` omits port binding (e.g. `- ports: 4200`) or defines a suitable port range (e.g. `- ports: 8000-8199:4200`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some ports from range `8080-8082` are already used. Also you are specifying only 3 ports when you are scaling to 5 services.

Use something like this and do not specify the port range to let docker select the available free ports automatically.

```
version : "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80
```

Comment: I scaled to 3 instances only, sorry for my error in my original post (see update). I also checked if all ports in the specified range are available. Trying a different port range (e. g. 50000:50002) results in the same problem. Your solution works, but I have to have full control over the assigned ports. With your solution one gets three instances with random host ports.